# How to connect Parse.com database to Amazon Redshift / other data warehousing tools

Tags: parse-platform, data-warehouse, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to setup a data warehouse to combine our Parse data with events/analytics data and make it easy to do analytics atop our data. At the moment, we're trying to set this up with Amazon Redshift.

With most databases, a JDBC or ODBC connector would work but given Parse doesn't allow direct database access, I'm not aware if/how to use these connectors.

How can I connect Parse to a Redshift instance? Or alternatively, are there other tools for data warehousing/doing analytics atop Parse + events data that would work better than Redshift?